# Magento - MegaMenu issue with background not floating to the left

Tags: css, magento, menu, themes, megamenu

I'm not sure if anyone can help with this, but I thought I would ask anyway.

http://www.acuity-sports.com/

I can get my mega menu background to fill out the background under the baseball tap with a left align, but on the softball tab with right align it will not fill out the background.

This one puzzles me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class .sm_megamenu_align_right try to put

```
left: auto !important;
```

Comment: This should work. @rundy just one question. If softball is the tab to come then why don't you put this as the last item in the `li` list items. That would make this less complicated right?

Comment: Thanks Mario!  I've been struggling with some aspects of this theme as as I continue to learn magento.